# how to accept value in date format in textbox in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Field in my windows form that asks user to enter their Birth Date...
How do i validate my form to accept only numbers and "/"( separator Symbol ) and also in dd/mm/yyyy format..
Also day should be less than 31, Month should be less than 12 and Year not greater than 2012

Comment: use datetime picker instead

Comment: You should use the DateTimePicker control instead.

Comment: Better you can use DateTime Control. If you want to use textbox only then design your self a user control for it.

Comment: The question is absolutely valid. Fellow dounvoters, do you think that if Ruchi Desai has known about DateTimePicker, he would ask that? Also answers are very useful if you search how to validate date field or some date input. StackOverflow sucks because of users like you.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to the exact same question and because Ruchi asked it I now know to use datetime picker. I agree with Miroslav, its a valid and useful question and not deserving of a downvote.

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` cannot be empty, but sometimes you need a date entry control to be empty; also if you know the exact date, entering it as text is often faster that picking a date in a (cumbersome) calender. Therefore this question is absolutely legitimate.

Answer (score 6):

Textbox is not the control to accept datetime input. There is a built in control `DateTimePicker` that should be used instead. The problem with your approach is that even if you do masking of textbox for one format like `dd/mm/yyyy` user may want to enter in `mm/dd/yyyy`. So, quite a lot of error handling. Whereas you need not worry about any such thing in case of `datetimepicker`.

Even then if you want to go with textbox. Do this,

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(yourTexbox.Text.Trim(), "yourformattoaccept", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   //your code if parsing is successful
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go for `DateTimePicker`, however we can also use a `TextBox` with some `Validating`. There are many kinds of validating data. We can prevent user from typing invalid data or we can also check the data after user submitting. Here I'll introduce you the second approach because the first requires more code to do, it may prevent user from typing invalid data but it also has to prevent user from **pasting** invalid data. That's why the first approach needs more code.

For the second approach you can add code to a `Validating` event handler for your `TextBox` and use a little `Regex` like this:

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$");
        Match m = reg.Match(textBox1.Text);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            int dd = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
            int mm = int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);
            int yyyy = int.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value);
            e.Cancel = dd < 1 || dd > 31 || mm < 1 || mm > 12 || yyyy > 2012;                
        }
        else e.Cancel = true;
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Wrong date format. The correct format is dd/mm/yyyy\n+ dd should be between 1 and 31.\n+ mm should be between 1 and 12.\n+ yyyy should be before 2013", "Invalid date", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Cancel)
                e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
```

You can add some `Submit` button to your form together with your `textBox1` to test. I hope you know how to register the `Validating` event handler for your `textBox1`.

Answer (score 1):

You make your life easier if you use the datatimepicker but if you still feel you want to present a textbox and help the user to prevent entering an illegal date this sample code will get you going.
I surpress keys and validate the textentry on exit of the field and prevent leaving if there is no valid date.

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        DateTime res;
        e.Cancel = !DateTime.TryParse(tb.Text, out res);
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
           // if you have an errorProvider...
           this.errorProvider1.SetError(
                 tb, 
                 String.Format("'{0}' is not a valid date", tb.Text));
        }
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // add extra checks to determine if
    // this char is allowed, set Handled to 
    // false. If you want to surpress the key
    // set it to true
    // get the current separator or have your own, then simply say @"/"
    var dateSep = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
    e.Handled = !(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ||
                (dateSep.IndexOf(e.KeyChar)>-1) ||
                Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do the validation after the user is done? In that case you could just try to parse the string as a date and see if it is a correct date. In that case you also get the days in month right.